# Is it posible to route requests for specific domains to different URL schemes?

Tags: django, django-urls

Is it possible to route requests for specific domains to different URL schemes in Django?

For example I have domains: `example.com` and `secret.com`. Is it possible to handle different URL schemes for different domain names?

Comment: That should happen in your web server (NGINX or Apache). Your Django application should match one specific domain.

Comment: @Guillaume, so i need to have two Django apps to solve this problem?

Comment: Well yes, now if the two Django app are identical, you can configure your web server so the url is linked to the same django app.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but just wanted to add this info for future visitors: This is possible with a small custom middleware as mentioned [in this article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/django-vhosts/):

```py
virtual_hosts = {
    "www.example-a.dev": "blog.urls",
    "www.example-b.dev": "links.urls",
    "www.example-c.dev": "links.urls",
}


class VirtualHostMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # let's configure the root urlconf
        host = request.get_host()
        request.urlconf = virtual_hosts.get(host)
        # order matters!
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

This will use a different `urls.py` file (i.e. `blog/urls.py` or `links/urls.py`) depending on the value of the `HTTP_HOST` header.